# calling a synchronous function (with call back) in foreach with the help of async.each

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

Sorry if my question seems simple to you! I'm so new to Node and callbacks! I have an async function (with a callback) called "find", also I have a an array which is called models; so I want to synchronously call this "find" function with each model in models and append the results in resultFound:

I appreciate your help! Please let me know if you need more clarification.

```
      st.find(param1, model, param2, param3, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.json(400, err);
            } else {
                res.json(200, data);
            }
        });
```

Here is my try (I believe having a return in st.find() is wrong; but I just mentioned my try to give you an insight of I'm trying to do!):

```
   var models = ["test1", "tes2"];
    var resultFound = [];
    async.each(models, find, function (err, data) {
        resultSearch.push(data);

    });

    function find(model) {
        st.find(param1, model, param2, param3, function (err, data) {
            return data;
        });
   }
```

Comment: Where is `res` coming from?

Comment: It is inside a router in Express; app.get('/test', function(req, res){})

Comment: You can probably do this with promises. See if this helps http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: I know it is doable with promises, but for some reason we should not use it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async`'s methods will pass a callback `function` to the `iterator`, in this case `find()`, that it expects to be called to know when to continue.

```
function find(model, callback) {
    st.find(param1, model, param2, param3, function (err, data) {
        callback(err, data);
    });

    // or possibly just:
    // st.find(param1, model, param2, param3, callback);
}
```

Though, [`async.each()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) isn't defined to expect `data` to be provided to the callback.

A method that will accept `data` is [`async.map()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#map), which will already create a new collection that you can use as `resultFound`.

```
var models = ["test1", "tes2"];

async.map(models, find, function (err, resultFound) {
    if (err) {
        res.json(400, err);
    } else {
        res.json(200, resultFound);
    }
});
```